# Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'

Tags: vb.net

I've been struggling for the past few hours and still can't get my head round this one . The issue I am having is when someone has been admitted  the database  updates giving them  BedID , when I then try and discharge them I can't seem to set the BedID (In the database)  to nothing . This is an issue as I need to be able to admit and discharge as many people as I can.

```
Sub Dis1_Click(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Dis1.ServerClick

    Dim time As String = Now().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

    sql = "UPDATE Allocation  SET BedID = NULL , DischargeDate =" + "'" + time + "'" + " WHERE BedID = 1 "
    cmd = New OdbcCommand(sql, cn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Sub BedCheck1()
    If r("BedID") = "" Then
    Else
        If r("BedID") = 1 Then
            ba = s & "<tr><td>" & r("Surname") & "</td>" & "<td>" & r("Forename") & "/<td>" & "<td>" & r("AdmitDate") & "</td>" & "<td>" & r("DischargeDate") & "</td>" & "<td>" & r("comments") & "</td></tr>"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to do a DbNull-check before you read the value:

```
If Not IsDbNull(r("BedID")) Then

    If r("BedID") = "" Then
    Else If r("BedID") = 1 Then
        ba = s & "<tr><td>" & r("Surname") & "</td>" & "<td>" & r("Forename") & "/<td>" & "<td>" & r("AdmitDate") & "</td>" & "<td>" & r("DischargeDate") & "</td>" & "<td>" & r("comments") & "</td></tr>"
    End If
End If
```

Note that DbNull is a special case and you need to use the IsDbNull-function to prevent this error

Comment: The DbNull can also be checked in 2 otherways. `r("BedID") IsNot DbNull.Value` and `Not TypeOf r("BedID") is DbNull` just to show all syntax options.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
if r("BedID").ToString = " " then

End If

Answer (score 0):

Well, Before you check data validation, you need to check is it DB null.

```
If Not IsDbNull(r("BedID")) Then
your code
End if
```