# Visual Basic 2012, having trouble with how to write DBNull. "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting the error listed above, and I've read elsewhere that what I have to do is do [a DBNull-check...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071869/operator-is-not-defined-for-type-dbnull-and-type-integer) but I just don't know how. I'm wondering if anyone would be able to assit me? I'm super new to VB.

I've also tried changing LedgerId and Net to Decimals, but then it tells me that this line:

```
JVNet += Net
```

is wrong. Something like "+ isn't valid for DBNull and Decimals".

Here's the relevant code (i think).

```
    Dim SQLStmt, LedgerId, NetDisp As String
    Dim Net, JVNet As Decimal
    Dim NetCounter As Integer
    Cnxn.Open()
    SQLStmt = "SELECT LedgerId, sum(Qty * Each) as Net FROM Orders, Details  where CONVERT(nvarchar(10), AcctgDate, 101) = '" & _
        cbJVDate.Text & _
        "' and Orders.Id = Details.OrderId group by LedgerId order by LedgerId"
    Dim JVCommand As New SqlCeCommand(SQLStmt, Cnxn)
    Dim JVReader As SqlCeDataReader
    lblAdvice.Text = ""
    Debug.Print(vbCrLf & "Got Here with '" & SQLStmt & "'" & vbCrLf)
    Try
        JVReader = JVCommand.ExecuteReader
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Execute JVReader with '" & SQLStmt & "' got " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    JVNet = 0
    NetCounter = 0
    lbJournal.Items.Clear()
    Do While JVReader.Read()
        LedgerId = JVReader.Item("LedgerId")
        Net = JVReader.Item("Net")
        JVNet += Net
        NetCounter += 1
        NetDisp = Format(Net, "0.00;(0.00)")
        NetDisp = NetDisp.PadLeft(10, " ")
        If Net < 0 Then NetDisp = " " & NetDisp
        lbJournal.Items.Add(LedgerId & NetDisp)
    Loop
    If NetCounter = 0 Then
        lblAdvice.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        lblAdvice.Text = "There are no details posted for " & cbJVDate.Text & "..."
    ElseIf JVNet = 0 Then
        lblAdvice.ForeColor = Color.Black
        lblAdvice.Text = "The journal for this date nets zero."
    Else
        lblAdvice.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        lblAdvice.Text = "The journal for this date does not net zero." & vbCrLf & _
           vbCrLf & "It nets " & Format(JVNet, "0.00")
    End If
    Cnxn.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For clarification, you are using SQL CE right? If so, SQL CE does not support the IFNULL or ISNULL function.

Comment: Yes, we are. Thank you for clarifying that for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB code, a database NULL is represent by `DBNull.Value`.  If you're getting data from a database then you might do something like this:

```
Dim str As String = Nothing
Dim int As Integer? = Nothing

If Not myDataRow.IsNull("Text") Then
    str = CStr(myDataRow("Text"))
End If

If Not myDataRow.IsNull("Number") Then
    int = CInt(myDataRow("Number"))
End If
```

Going the other way, you might do something like this:

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET Text = @Text, Number = @Number WHERE ID = @ID", connection)

command.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(str Is Nothing, CObj(DBNull.Value), str)
command.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = If(int.HasValue, int.Value, CObj(DBNull.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL CE does not support the IFNULL or ISNULL function, to replicate the function, one way is to use the CASE..END construct:

```
SQLStmt = "SELECT LedgerId, 
CASE SUM(Qty * Each) IS NULL THEN 0 END AS Net
FROM Orders, Details
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(10), AcctgDate, 101) = '" & cbJVDate.Text & "' AND Orders.Id = Details.OrderId
GROUP BY LedgerId ORDER BY LedgerId"
```

The other way is to use COALESCE (which I cant test because I dont have SQL CE)

```
SQLStmt = "SELECT LedgerId, 
CAOLESCE(SUM(Qty * Each),0) AS Net
FROM Orders, Details
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(10), AcctgDate, 101) = '" & cbJVDate.Text & "' AND Orders.Id = Details.OrderId
GROUP BY LedgerId ORDER BY LedgerId"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I replaced the SQL statement and now it returns: 

"Execute JVReader with 'SELECT LedgerId, IFNULL(sum(Qty*Each),0) as Net FROM Orders, Details WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(10), AcctgDate, 101) = '07/29*=/2014' ANDOrders.Id = Details.OrderId " GROUP BY LEdgerId ORDER BY LedgerId' got There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 131, Token in error = ANDOrders]

Comment: Kindly checked again there are some Typo's in the query

Comment: Sorry, I cant edit my previous comment. Here's the edit: 

EDIT: I fixed a few syntax errors i made and now it says: [ Token line number=1,Token line offset = 117, Token in error = 07/29/2014]

It doesn't make sense to me because that's from the db.

(Thank you so much for your assistance)